# Export CSV. Folder, subfolder and file into separate column

Tags: powershell, csv, export

I created a script that lists all the folders, subfolders and files and export them to csv:

```
$path = "C:\tools"
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse |select fullname | export-csv -Path "C:\temp\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

But I would like that each folder, subfolder and file in pfad is written into separate column in csv.

Something like this:

c:\tools\test\1.jpg

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tools | test | 1.jpg |

I will be grateful for any help.

Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you have `C:\tools\test\another\1.jpg` ? A whole new column the others don't have? Combine with one of the other columns? Overall, initially, this sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Amount of subfolders will be constant

Answer (score 1):

You can split the `Fullname` property using the `Split()` method. The tricky part is that you need to know the maximum path depth in advance, as the CSV format requires that all rows have the same number of columns (even if some columns are empty).

```
# Process directory $path recursively
$allItems = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

    # Split on directory separator (typically '\' for Windows and '/' for Unix-like OS)
    $FullNameSplit = $_.FullName.Split( [IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar )  

    # Create an object that contains the splitted path and the path depth.
    # This is implicit output that PowerShell captures and adds to $allItems.
    [PSCustomObject] @{ 
        FullNameSplit = $FullNameSplit
        PathDepth     = $FullNameSplit.Count
    }
}

# Determine highest column index from maximum depth of all paths.
# Minus one, because we'll skip root path component.
$maxColumnIndex = ( $allItems | Measure-Object -Maximum PathDepth ).Maximum - 1

$allRows = foreach( $item in $allItems ) {

    # Create an ordered hashtable
    $row = [ordered]@{}

    # Add all path components to hashtable. Make sure all rows have same number of columns.
    foreach( $i in 1..$maxColumnIndex ) {
        $row[ "Column$i" ] = if( $i -lt $item.FullNameSplit.Count ) { $item.FullNameSplit[ $i ] } else { $null }
    }

    # Convert hashtable to object suitable for output to CSV.
    # This is implicit output that PowerShell captures and adds to $allRows.
    [PSCustomObject] $row
} 

# Finally output to CSV file
$allRows | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

**Notes:**

- The syntax `Select-Object @{ Name= ..., Expression = ... }` creates a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1).
- `$allRows = foreach` captures and assigns all output of the `foreach` loop to variable `$allRows`, which will be an array if the loop outputs more than one object. This works with most other control statements as well, e. g. `if` and `switch`.
- Within the loop I could have created a `[PSCustomObject]` directly (and used `Add-Member` to add properties to it) instead of first creating a hashtable and then converting to `[PSCustomObject]`. The choosen way should be faster as no additional overhead for calling cmdlets is required.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunatelly i receive an error in line 9:Measure-Object : The property " $_.FullNameSplit.Count " cannot be found in the input for any objects

Comment: @EloBizne The code required PS7+ because older PS versions don't support calculated properties for `Measure-Object`. I've slightly changed the code to support PS5 as well.

Comment: thank you, it works perfect! I have to do also second script, with constant amount od subfolders (measure-object ist not necessary). Inthis script the first column should have title "Project" and always the same value "Accounting". The second should habe title "1 Subfolder" and get the 1 Subfolder name as value. 3 column should has title "file" and as value file namem and the 4 colums should have title "date created" and  take creation file date as value. I tied to convert your script to do this, but I thing it will be not working.

Comment: @EloBizne Comments are not supposed to be used for follow-up questions. Please create a new question if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

While a file with rows containing a variable number of items is not actually a CSV file, you can roll your own and Microsoft Excel can read it.

=== Get-DirCsv.ps1

```
Get-Childitem -File |
    ForEach-Object {
        $NameParts = $_.FullName -split '\\'
        $QuotedParts = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
        foreach ($NamePart in $NameParts) {
            $QuotedParts.Add('"' + $NamePart + '"') | Out-Null
        }
        Write-Output $($QuotedParts -join ',')
    }
```

Use this to capture the output to a file with:

```
.\Get-DirCsv.ps1 | Out-File -FilePath '.\dir.csv' -Encoding ascii
```